# change columns order using multicols

Tags: lyx, multicol, hebrew, bidi

I've divided a **Hebrew** paragraph to 3 columns, using `\begin{multicols}{3}` with `\end{multicols}`.

The problem (since in Hebrew we write from right to left) is that the columns came up in the opposite order: (I II and III should be in reversed order)
[image]

Is there a way to change it?

example code:
[image]

By the way, is there a way to add a line between the columns?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please add a minimal example of LaTeX code?

Comment: the `bidi` package should work with `multicol` to re-order the columns, but i do not know how to use from lynx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look into the documentation of `multicols`, i.e., `multicol.pdf` you will find this question answered: use `\RLmulticolcolumns` to change the order to right-to-left.

As David mentioned, the bidi package should also work with multicol, though there have been some incompatibilities in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Following [Guy Rutenberg](https://www.guyrutenberg.com/2015/03/20/hebrew-with-xetex-example/)'s recommendation, I'm using `XeLaTeX`. I don't know how did you get your wrong column order (you didn't post a MWE...), but in my configuration there is no need to do anything special in order to get right to left support for `multicol`.

Here's an example code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{multicol}   

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Times New Roman}[Script=Hebrew]

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}

א בְּרֵאשִׁית, בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם, וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ.  ב וְהָאָרֶץ, הָיְתָה תֹהוּ וָבֹהוּ, וְחֹשֶׁךְ, עַל-פְּנֵי תְהוֹם; וְרוּחַ אֱלֹהִים, מְרַחֶפֶת עַל-פְּנֵי הַמָּיִם.  ג וַיֹּאמֶר אֱלֹהִים, יְהִי אוֹר; וַיְהִי-אוֹר.  ד וַיַּרְא אֱלֹהִים אֶת-הָאוֹר, כִּי-טוֹב; וַיַּבְדֵּל אֱלֹהִים, בֵּין הָאוֹר וּבֵין הַחֹשֶׁךְ.  ה וַיִּקְרָא אֱלֹהִים לָאוֹר יוֹם, וְלַחֹשֶׁךְ קָרָא לָיְלָה; וַיְהִי-עֶרֶב וַיְהִי-בֹקֶר, יוֹם אֶחָד.  {פ}
ו וַיֹּאמֶר אֱלֹהִים, יְהִי רָקִיעַ בְּתוֹךְ הַמָּיִם, וִיהִי מַבְדִּיל, בֵּין מַיִם לָמָיִם.  ז וַיַּעַשׂ אֱלֹהִים, אֶת-הָרָקִיעַ, וַיַּבְדֵּל בֵּין הַמַּיִם אֲשֶׁר מִתַּחַת לָרָקִיעַ, וּבֵין הַמַּיִם אֲשֶׁר מֵעַל לָרָקִיעַ; וַיְהִי-כֵן.  ח וַיִּקְרָא אֱלֹהִים לָרָקִיעַ, שָׁמָיִם; וַיְהִי-עֶרֶב וַיְהִי-בֹקֶר, יוֹם שֵׁנִי.  {פ}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```